# Sending my first email in Python SMTP - using "with" is invalid syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, email

I'm following a class online and I'm doing as the instructor does. They used a with block for this bit of code to send the email, but it gives me an SyntaxError. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, I followed the exact same steps.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

#Replaced email, name, & password w/ filler

message = MIMEMultipart()
message["from"] = "First_Name Last_Name"
message["to"] = "email@email.com"
message["subject"] = "This is a test"
message.attach(MIMEText("Body")

with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login("email@email.com", "password1234")
    smtp.send_message(message)
    print("Sent...")
```

Here's the error I get:

```
  File "c:\Users\Mofongo\Google Drive\HelloWorld\app.py", line 11
    with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as smtp:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in the message.attach(MIMEText("Body")).